# ant file build failed due to below errors

Tags: java, ant, build

When I try to run ant file the build is going to fail because of the below reasons:

```
[projectBuild] null DN Jaxb Beans:Multiple output locations are disabled, cannot associate entry: 'DN Jaxb Beans/src' with a specific output.
[projectBuild] null DN Jaxb Beans:Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [J2SE-1.5]'.
[projectBuild] null DN Jaxb Beans:Unbound classpath container: 'org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER'.
[projectBuild] null DN Jaxb Beans:Multiple output locations are disabled, cannot associate entry: 'DN Jaxb Beans/src' with a specific output.
[projectBuild] null DN Jaxb Beans:The project was not built since its classpath is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the classpath then try rebuilding this project.
[projectBuild] 1 JAXBVersion.java:This compilation unit indirectly references the missing type java.lang.Object (typically some required class file is referencing a type outside the classpath)
[projectBuild] Errors were detected after building DN Jaxb Beans
[projectBuild] ProjectBuild: DN Jaxb Beans Exception=Errors were detected after building DN Jaxb Beans
[projectBuild] BUILD FAILED: file:C:/workspace.May21/DN Ant Scripts/buildDev.xml:149: 

ProjectBuild: DN Jaxb Beans Exception=Errors were detected after building DN Jaxb Beans
Total time: 19 minutes 4 seconds
```

could you please solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following error is a good indication:

```
Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object
```

If java cannot find `java.lang.Object` then there are configuration problems with your java install.  The message `JRE System Library [J2SE-1.5]` looks like an eclipse jre configuration name so I assume you are running this through eclipse.  I would try removing and adding back in the execution environment config in eclipse.

Comment: i am running in WebSphere Application Developer. Configured Java 1.4.

Comment: Your project seems to be configured for java 1.5.  Check your project settings to see what version of java it is looking for and your workspace settings to see what versions of java you have available.

Comment: i configured preferences again and set all in the correct manner. Then it started correctly.